# Assign the values of has_and_belongs_to_many field at a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to assign groups to user at a view using html tag `select`.

```
#model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  attr_accessible :groups, #......
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end


#controller
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @groups = Group.all.map{|x| [x.name, x.id]}
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new params[:user]
    # @user.groups
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = 'ok'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

#view
= form_for @user, url: {action: 'create'} do |f|
  = f.label :group
  = f.select :groups, @groups
```

and the part of the post `params`

```
{ ....
  "groups"=>"1"
  ...
}
```

what it now says is that `"undefined method`each' for "1":String"`. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have groups in a array, and add the multiple option (if a user should have more then one group) like this:

```
#view
= form_for @user, url: {action: 'create'} do |f|
  = f.label :group
  = f.select :groups, [@groups], {}, { :multiple => true }
```

However personally i prefer to use 'collection_select' when working with models:

```
#controller
def new
  @user = User.new
  @groups = Group.all
end

#view
= form_for @user, url: {action: 'create'} do |f|
  = f.label :group
  = f.collection_select(:group_ids, @groups, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => true })
```

Comment: I have the error saying `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: group_ids`

Comment: add `attr_accessible :group_ids` to your `User` model :)

Comment: Actually im not totally sure this will work with `has_and_belongs_to_many`, but i know it works with `has_many`... please comment if you run into more problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a select statement only lets you select one group. So, thats more like belongs_to relationship. Lets assume that you want a "has_and_belongs_to_many" relation, and you have created the required join table, you can use a checkboxes to select groups. Something like

```
<% for group in Group.find(:all) %>
   <div>
        <%= check_box_tag "user[group_ids][]", group.id, @user.groups.include?(category) %>
        <%= group.name %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```